# Переход по ссылке со своим значением

Tags: php

Добрый вечер профессионалы. Вот как мне сделать, что бы переходя по ссылке  (допустим их здесь пять), ссылка присваивала своё значение для переменной dep ?
Я так понял это делается через сессии $session_start, может я не прав?

```
<?php
$arr=array();
$arr[0]='запись1';
$arr[1]='запись2';
$arr[2]='запись3';
$arr[3]='запись4';
$arr[4]='запись5';
for ($j = 0; $j < count($arr); $j++) { 
echo '<a href="http://localhost/test.php?dep='.$arr[$j].'">'. $arr[$j] . '</a><br>'; }
echo $dep;
?>
```

Да, еще, сейчас у меня маленькая ошибка в этом скрипте, так как переменная dep неправильно объявлена, как я понял. но не суть..

Comment: вы бы лучше начали изучение пхп с чтения книг, а не попыток написать что-то.

Comment: Не надо вам тут ни каких сессий, если данные вы пересылаете через адресную строку. И переменной `$dep` у вас сейчас еще нет, она появится тогда, когда вы своем браузере тыкните на одну из данных ссылок. Читайте ответ ниже от Jurij Jazdanov.

Answer (score 2):

после того как перешли по ссылки с переменной, до нее можно достучаться через глобальный массив $_GET

```
if (isset($_GET['dep']) { // проверяем существует ли $_GET['dep']
    echo $_GET['dep'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Просто на странице test.php сверху пишите

```
session_start();
if(!empty($_REQUEST["dep"])){
     $_SESSION["DEP_VALUE"] = $_REQUEST["dep"];
}
```

А если нужно использовать просто, то тогда, как вам ответили выше.

Comment: Это ужасный ответ.

Comment: @Visman буду благодарен, если укажите на ошибку.

Comment: Весь ответ ошибка, так как запутывает автора вопроса еще больше.

Comment: @Visman Прекрасный комментарий.